# Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslation' when using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, junit

I am having a problem with JUnit test using Powermock. I want to mock final class object looking like this - created via builder:

```
public final class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static ReferenceStep builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
```

I need to test the method that uses this object (Request) but don't need to test the Request itself. So I wrote a test:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Rule;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // <-this leads to error
@PrepareForTest( { Request.class })
public class Test1 {
    private static final String acc1 = "acc1";
    private static final String acc2 = "acc2";
    private aService aService;
    private tService tService;

    @Before
    public void setupTestConditionsBeforeEachTest() throws Exception {
        Factory Factory = (Factory) Class.forName(
            "example.FactoryImpl").newInstance();
        aService = bankFactory.getAccountService();
        tService = bankFactory.getTransferService();        
        Factory.setupInitialData();     
    }

    @Test
    public void doTransfer() throws Exception {
        aService.createAccount(CASH_ACCOUNT_1,100);
        aService.createAccount(CASH_ACCOUNT_2,0);

        TransactionLeg leg1 = new TransactionLeg(CASH_ACCOUNT_1,MoneyUtils.toMoney("10.00", "EUR"));
        TransactionLeg leg2 = new TransactionLeg(CASH_ACCOUNT_1,MoneyUtils.toMoney("-10.00", "EUR"));
        //used later for Request
        List<TransactionLeg> legs = new ArrayList<TransactionLeg>();
        legs.add(leg1);
        legs.add(leg2);
        Request tested = PowerMockito.mock(Request.class);
        PowerMockito.when(tested.getLegs()).thenReturn(legs);
        PowerMockito.when(tested.getTransactionRef()).thenReturn("First transaction");
        PowerMockito.when(tested.getTransactionType()).thenReturn("Type1");

        tService.transferFunds(tested);
    }
    }
}
```

So the method to be tested is transferFunds. I only need Request class to pass as parameter to this function. Ok I run this test and get an error:

```
Tests in error:
doTransfer(...Test1): Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslation'                             defined in class path resource [.../config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]:            Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCrea
tionException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean'     defined in class path resource [.../config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]:     Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is     javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: banktest_pu] Unable to
build EntityManagerFactory
```

Using Maven. pom looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It seems that the problem is in Spring configuration. But I don't know where to dig in the problem. Alternatively, is there any way to avoid using mock? The class Transfer is made using builder() so I don't see how to put test values in it(and I also cannot change any part of the code)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite clear your problem description. In your test you mock calls to your Request class (getLegs etc.), but I do not see these methods in your class definition. On the other hand I do not see how you mock the static builder() method (I assume this is what you want?).

Comment: Sorry having a bit of mess in the head(just starting messing with junits). I want to mock Request object - because I want to simulate the result coming from Request.getLegs() (I just want to get some Request object for testing the method transferFunds that uses it as parameter). Maybe it's a bad approach. Methods like getLegs() are defined for Request class:     public List<TransactionLeg> getLegs() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(legs);
    }

Comment: Ok, this is a valid approach, and this is exactly what the mocking framework is intended to do. The PowerMock comes into play if you want to mock static methods or constructors. If you do not need this, avoid to let the test run with PowerMockRunner and it is neither necessary to use the PrepareForTest annotation.

Comment: I cannot use normal mock() because the class Request is final(and I cannot change the code) - so the normal usage of mock() returns error.

Comment: the error message tells me that some of your involved classes obviously use (spring?) beans (e.g. PersistenceJPAConfig.class). But your pasted code does not show anything like this. For testing a single class it is mostly not needed to load the spring framework, just mock the involved beans.

Comment: I know PowerMock in conjunction with EasyMock, not with Mockito. There I would have to replay the mocked class after having finished the recording: PowerMock.replay( tested)

Comment: Thanks for your hints, Yes this is Spring framework-related error, however, I don't see the connection between this and usage of PowerMock(I am not the developer of this app just testing it, so don't know much details how to configure it). Can you give some examples of mocking the bean?